# SML map a filter?

Tags: sml, fold

If I have this code:

```
fun coord_select (x : int, cs : (int*int) list) =
         List.filter (fn (first, _) => first = x ) cs
```

testing with input gives this:

```
coord_select (2, [(2,2),(2,3),(3,3),(4,3)])
: val it = [(2,2),(2,3)] : (int * int) list
```

Now, what if I don't give the desired first coordinate as an `int` but as a list of several required first coordinates such as [3,4], i.e., I want all coordinate tuples that start with 3 as well as 4? The easy way would simply to create a recursive wrapper around this that went through the list and plugged in the value as `coord_select`'s first variable. But I would like to understand nested things better than such brute force. So I came up with this:

```
fun coord_match (fs : int list, cs :(int*int) list) =
         map (coord_select (f, cs)) fs
```

but this can't really work because, as was pointed out, `coord_select` in the `map` is actually trying to return a list -- and how does `map` know to plug in the members of `fs` into `f` in the first place? Common Lisp does have a device to keep functions like this from running, i.e., the `'` operator. But this wouldn't help, again, because `map` doesn't know which variable `fs` is supplying. For input, e.g., I have these coordinates:

```
[(2,2),(2,3),(3,3),(4,3)]
```

and I have this list of x-coordinates to match against the above list

```
[3,4]
```

Again, I could just put a recursive wrapper around this, but I'm reaching for a more elegant nested solution from the greater `fold` family.

Comment: Work out all the types first. For instance, `coord_select (f, cs)` is an `(int * int) list`, not a function (or would be, if `f` existed), and mapping an `'a -> 'b list` function over an `'a list` would produce a `'b list list`, not a `'b list`. (Hint: research folds.)

Comment: I think I see now. IOW, my `coord_select (f, cs)` inside the `map` is returning a list of tuples, i.e., it's not an applicable function. Alas, beginner's non-luck....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional in ML map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53822272/conditional-in-ml-map)

Comment: @Simon Shine: It's a continuation. The only thing different is that before, I only had it filter for one coordinate value. This time for a list of values. Actually, your `filter` suggestion is how I solved it. See above for how I implemented it.

Comment: @147pm: In that case, it's a little unclear what you're asking. Since what you're asking is a yes/no question, would you be content with "Yes"? Perhaps if you expanded on what it is you're doing and contained the question to one Q&A, rather than one for each step in the learning process, this wouldn't qualify as "duplicate", or "unclear", or being an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Good. I'll delete the last one. It wasn't the whole story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what if I don't give the desired first coordinate as an int but as a list of several required first coordinates such as [3,4], i.e., I want all coordinate tuples that start with 3 and 4

It sounds like you want all coordinate tuples that start with 3 *or* 4, since a coordinate can't both be 3 *and* 4.

Given that, you can write `coord_select` like:

```
fun member (x, xs) =
    List.exists (fn x2 => x = x2) xs

fun coord_select (xs, coords) =
    List.filter (fn (x, _) => member (x, xs)) coords
```

> the greater `fold` family

This family is called [*catamorphisms*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catamorphism), of which `map`, `filter`, `exists` and `foldl` belong. Since `foldl` is the most general of these, it is technically possible to write the code above using folds entirely:

```
fun coord_select (xs, coords) =
    foldr (fn ((x, y), acc1) =>
      if foldl (fn (x2, acc2) => acc2 orelse x = x2) false xs
      then (x, y) :: acc1
      else acc1) [] coords
```

but as should be evident, explicit folds are not very readable.

If there's a specialised combinator that does a job, you would rather want that over a fold. And if it doesn't exist, creating it from slightly less specialised combinators improves readability. Folding is as close to manual recursion as you get and so provides little information to the reader about what kind of recursion we're attempting.

For that reason I also made `member` from `exists`, since `exists` requires me to specify a predicate and my predicate is "equality with `x`"; so even `exists`, I feel, adds clutter to the `coord_select` function.

You can learn more about list catamorphisms in functional programming by reading [Functional Programming with Bananas, Lenses, Envelopes and Barbed Wire](https://maartenfokkinga.github.io/utwente/mmf91m.pdf) (1991) by Meijer, Fokkinga, Paterson.

Comment: Thanks. Using `exists` then `filter` did it more elegantly, although the increase in complexity in going from just one first coordinate to a list of first coordinates has proven to be a bit daunting. I'm impressed at how `member` neatly provides a boolean just like the conditional part of `filter` is expecting. I was missing this important point, i.e., `filter` wants a `true` or `false` a la "does it exist?" This is exactly the learning experience I was wanting out of this. I hope others else can benefit.